# How to use Google Drive API using AWS Lambda with Java(Springboot)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to implement AWS Lambda function that can read a particular file from Google drive.

I'm very new to AWS & also not much familiar with Google Drive API.

What I've done is, I used Google drive API's Quick start program and made required modifications & also did suggested settings on https://console.developers.google.com/ and it's working fine from the local machine.

Now exact problem I'm facing is, I am trying to deploy it to AWS Lambda, it's running proper, but as Google drive API document suggests, it'll provide a link when we run the program for the first time, and paste that link in browser and authenticate. It'll store the token for future reference, that means basically it stores token on our machine. And this part is working fine when I run it from my local machine, but from AWS Lambda.

It's giving redirect-error after authenticating from browser. Also, AWS Lambda only allows to write into `/tmp` directory, so I also made those changes to store into `/tmp` as you can see in below snippet.
so, when I test the Lambda Function, it gives me the link to paste in browse & authenticate, but when I do it, it's authenticating properly but is seems some issue while redirecting.
I think is's a problem related to **redirect_uri**

what should be **redirect_uri**  to read from Google drive using AWS Lambda?

for local, the redirect_uri I set on Google http://localhost:8888/Callback

quick-start code from Google-drive that I'm sharing the code that I'm following.

```
package com.lambda.demo.handler;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

public class LambdaRequestHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Drive API call using AWS Lambda";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "/tmp";

    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = LambdaRequestHandler.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                        .setAccessType("offline").build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {

        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

            Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            service.files().get("1QL0ez7mTPQZy1TSnnxMyEB6yHiKn8W2f").executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int ch; (ch = in.read()) != -1;) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            }
            System.out.println("in : " + sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is how my Google developer console setting for redirect-url looks like,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the type of credentials you created on Google developer console.  Your code uses `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp` which is for use with installed applications. For this you should have created desktop credentials or other.

If you check the [Java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) it actually states

> - Complete the steps described in the rest of this page to create a **simple Java command-line application** that makes requests to the Drive API.
> - Authorization credentials for a **desktop application**. To learn how to create credentials for a desktop application, refer to Create credentials

Desktop credentials use the refresh token but its auto configured for you to always return to the location the request came from.  As it is an installed application eh browser window will always be opening on the machine that the code is running on.

For a web application we need a redirect URI to be configured since the browser window will need to run on the client or the users machine not on the server the code is running on. Note the code that uses a [web browser credential](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications) is different from your code. Thats why your web browser client won't work with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting the things you're suggesting but from the link that you shared for web browser credential, I still could not figure out how I can use it to call API from AWS Lambda function!

Comment: I guess what i am trying to point out is that i'm not sure how it is you think you can get it to work with  AWS Lambda function.  I have zero experience with AWS but if its anything like Google cloud functions, there is no user interaction there's no way for you to present a browser window to a user.  There for the normal stratforward method of Oauth2 authorization isnt going to work.  IF the data you are trying to access is internal data, as in data that you personally control. and not data owned by your users, then i would suggest you try using a service account.

Comment: Okay as you stated, using Google cloud function, how you'd authenticate function to read a file from Google drive?

Comment: I would use a service account assuming that the file i am reading is on my own drive account.   If it was a users file then i would not be using a function.   I have a video explanation of a service account here,  the video itself is for downloading from Google drive with C#.  But if you start at this point this should explain what a service account is https://youtu.be/VQOrkZrZXB8?t=63